# Wait for a response during a feature test using lettuce+splinter and django

Tags: django, bdd, lettuce

Short story:
I am writing a feature test for a django app using lettuce and splinter.
The scenario fails due to some lack of sync at the step calls.

The question:
Is there a way to prevent this error from happening wihtout adding an artificial waiting time to my step?

Longer story:
The scenario checks if an existing user is able to log in.

```
Scenario: User exists as admin
    Given I access the url "/login/"
    And The user "someuser" with password "something" exists as admin
    When I fill username with "someuser" and password with "exists"
    And I submit the form        
    Then I see the paragraph "You're successfully logged in!"
```

the critical step here is:

```
@step(r'I see the paragraph "(.*)"')
def see_paragraph(step, text):
    assert text in world.browser.html
```

When I harvest the lettuce feature, it randomly fails.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/lettuce/core.py", line 143, in __call__
    ret = self.function(self.step, *args, **kw)
  File "/vagrant/src/enext/apps/auth/features/authentication-steps.py", line 21, in see_paragraph
    assert text in world.browser.html
AssertionError
```

When I tried to debug it, I found that printing the response would make it work every time, so I could not reproduce the error. Adding a pause also seems to do the trick.

```
@step(r'I see the paragraph "(.*)"')
def see_paragraph(step, text):
    # print world.browser.html.encode('utf-8')
    # either the next or the previous line fixes it
    time.sleep(0.3)
    assert text in world.browser.html
```

At first it looked like it was related to the test database flush, but I removed the other scenarios, and the flush as well, and it kept happening.

Comment: No love for lettuce?
For now I will stick to my active wait. But I'm still interested in this. If anyone finds something new, let me know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might depend on what your `And I submit the form` makes. If this step clicks on "submit" button or something like that then it's the place where the problem starts.

Webdriver waits for page to load almost after all actions except clicking and other "onpage" interactions. So after click it immediately looks for presence of element without waiting for response.

As a solution I would recommend you to use `wait_time` argument as described at [splinter docs](http://splinter.cobrateam.info/docs/matchers.html#checking-the-presence-of-text) or write your own function that goes in a loop of checking statement until specified timeout.

P.S.: I also recommend you to look at [python selenium](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium) and it's `wait(browser, timeout).until(some_statement)`

Comment: As it turns out, I do use click on the submit button. The step definition does: `world.browser.find_by_css('input[type="submit"]').first.click()`

Comment: I'll try then using `browser.is_text_present('text', wait_time=0.3)`, but this is basically the same I was already doing. More nicely written though.

Comment: if you use timeout, it checks if statement is `True` all the time, so if you even make `wait_time=10` it won't be any difference in actual time. But in this case you will protect your test from failing if it takes 0.5s instead of 0.3s

Comment: I see now. This is perfect then.